# Building a Conditional JPQL Statement

Tags: spring-boot, expression, conditional-statements, jpql

Here is a JPQL statement that I currently have defining a repository method in Spring Boot.

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Station s WHERE s.latitude <= (:latitude + .5) AND"
       + "s.latitude >= (:latitude - .5) AND "
       + "s.longitude <= (:longitude + .5) AND "
       + "s.longitude >= (:longitude - .5)")
List<Station> findAllNear(@Param("latitude") double latitude,
                          @Param("longitude") double longitude);
```

The premise behind this statement is I want to find any and all stations within a 1 degree by 1 degree box around the given coordinates if any. I am not concerned with actual distance, as the results will be refined by my business logic elsewhere.

The problem I have is this will not work well around the 180 degree longitude (nor around the poles, but I am not as concerned about that as the likelihood at this juncture of us querying that far north is slim)

Specifically, if someone were to ask for a location at or around 180 degrees longitude, it would not find stations at -179.5 or closer.

How should I adjust the JPQL to handle these cases? Is the only approach to also test for +- 360 degrees on the longitude? Is it possible to cluster groups in this way using JPQL?

```
A && B && ((C && D) || (E && F) || (G && H))
```

The JPQL Language documentation says that parentheses are allowed in an expression, but it lists AND and OR as between expression operators. Can AND and OR exist within parentheses?

Also, is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JPQL allows in between expressions within parentheses, so an argument of the form

```
A && B && ((C && D) || (E && F) || (G && H))
```

is valid. Changing my select statement to:

```
@Query("SELECT s FROM Station s WHERE (s.latitude <= (:latitude + .5) AND"
   + "s.latitude >= (:latitude - .5)) AND "
   + "(s.longitude <= (:longitude + .5) AND s.longitude >= (:longitude - .5)) OR "
   + "(s.longitude <= (:longitude + 360.5) AND s.longitude >= (:longitude +359.5)) OR "
   + "(s.longitude <= (:longitude - 359.5) AND s.longitude >= (:longitude - 360.5)))")
List<Station> findAllNear(@Param("latitude") double latitude,
                      @Param("longitude") double longitude);
```

Accomplished what I set out to do.

Comment: Seeing as this is a partial answer to my question, in that I do not know if there is a simpler way, I will not accept this unless I get agreement that this is the easiest way to perform this task.